# How to execute JavaScript inside an attribute?

Tags: javascript, html, attributes

I want to link a php file I have to javascript file. However, my javascript file is saved on my local computer.
I learned that I can use  `URL.createobjectURL('file:///Users/myUser/documents/myJsFile')` to turn the local link into an HTTP link, but the problem is I cannot run that method inside of the src attribute as such.

```
<script src="URL.createobjectURL('file:///Users/myUser/documents/myJsFile')"></script>
```

Is there any way I can run javascript inside the attribute?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to use a production method: i.e. setup a real server. If you use php it is likely you already have apache so you could just put `myFile.js` inside a public folder and use something like `/myJsFile.js` (with / it will use same domain name and port: ideal when going in production.)

Comment: I'm sorry but I am very new to PHP and local servers. How would I go about doing that step by step?

Comment: Do you follow a tutorial ?

Comment: I've been looking for tutorials for that but I can't find one

Comment: Ok so follow https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_install.asp and https://www.php.net/manual/en/install.php or if you don't want to setup locally use online host lie 000webhost, heroku, ...

Comment: You misunderstood me. I have PHP installed, and it is already running on a web server. I was asking how would you put /myFile.js in a public server?

Comment: You have somewhere index.php and a URL to access the rendered content of index.php  just put your file next to index.php (or in a subfolder) and you should have a new URL you can use. replace index.php by myFile.js sometime you only have a / and no index.php so just be sure it end with `/myFile.js` and put that URL in src attribute.

Comment: Thank you very much, I just added myFile.js file and added it's URL to the src attribute but it is not working. I even tried checking by just running an alert('test') and nothing happens

Comment: check your browser dev tool you might have a network tab that will say if the path is correct ( a refresh might be needed once open) or console tab